# How to change the password of user of root in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am new to Apache IoTDB and am trying to learn about administration management. I have a question about user settings: can the password of the "root" user be changed?

If it can be changed, how should I change it in Apache IoTDB?

Comment: I found this: https://iotdb.apache.org/UserGuide/V1.0.x/Administration-Management/Administration.html#list-of-privileges-included-in-the-system. Look for MODIFY_PASSWORD.